# Run Wix 4 Custom Action in 64bit process

Tags: windows, uwp, wix, windows-installer, wix4

We are trying to get the Program Files folder on Windows in a custom action using  Wix 4 toolset. The custom action will register a Sparse package in the program files directory.
Of course it needs to be the correct folder depending on whether it is an x64 or x86 build.

The problem is the custom action is always returning the Program Files x86 folder even if its an x64 build ie the WiX MSI installer is 64 bit and the whole app is built for 64 bit. The Custom action dll project is built for AnyCPU, attempting to only build for x64 causes the dll not to load at all.

```
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

We put some code in the custom action like below which is always returning false. We also see the following log

```
 var is64bit = Environment.Is64BitProcess.ToString();
 session.Log("is64bit {0}", is64bit);

 Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server
```

How can we get the correct Program Files directory depedending on whether its a 64bit or 32bit build?

Thanks